# Child element not fitting perfectly over a parent with border radius and border style applied

Tags: css

As you can see in the screenshot, when there is a border radius and border style applied to the parent element,and the child element sits "above" the parent via "position:absolute" it seems that some of the image in the background is "bleeding" through in the corners.

This effect is noticeable when the color if the border and background color of the child are the same. This is present in all major browsers, so I'm guessing it's not bug?

[image: screenshot of the effect]

Is there a fix for this?

http://codepen.io/iki_xx/pen/EpJmb

Comment: This is common, in my experience. Just always assumed it was due to browser math rounding issues when calculating the radius of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have to 10px border. I just change the border to 0 and the size of the box didn't change and the bleed-through from the image disappears.